# Indirect function in array with if statement

Tags: excel

I have the following function

=IF([A68U.SI.csv]A68U.SI!$G$3:$G$1000="","",[A68U.SI.csv]A68U.SI!$G$3:$G$1000)

Here, I would like to replace A68U.SI with the entry in cell C1, which contains the text "A68U.SI".

I tried the following formula but am getting an error:

=IF((INDIRECT("[" & C1 & ".csv]" & C1 & "!"))$G$3:$G$1000="","",INDIRECT("[" & C1 & ".csv]" & C1 & "!"))$G$3:$G$1000)

Does anyone have an idea what's wrong?

As always, many thanks!

Comment: The [INDIRECT function](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/indirect-function-21f8bcfc-b174-4a50-9dc6-4dfb5b3361cd) cannot be used on external references. If you are interested in the third-party MOREFUNC library's INDIRECT.EXT function which can be used externally, I try to keep a clean copy [here](http://1drv.ms/1FGgIdG).

Comment: Thank you. The problem with MOREFUNC is that it does not work in Excel 2100 64bit. Is there any other solution?

Comment: Indirect works with external references if the other file is open. That is your only other option.

Answer (score 0):

try

```
=iferror(IF((INDIRECT("[" & C1 & ".csv]" & C1 & "!"))$G$3:$G$1000="","",INDIRECT("[" & C1 & ".csv]" & C1 & "!"))$G$3:$G$1000),"Please open the file "&C1&".csv")
```

Comment: Thanks, that's inventive!